# Memory leak when using Automaper version 6.0.0 .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm currently utilizing Automaper for mapping a model object to an entity object. Both object types share identical structures, with most inner object properties possessing similar attributes. However, an issue arises when attempting to map to the entity, resulting in a significant increase in RAM memory usage. It's worth noting that this process functioned flawlessly until new inner collections were introduced to the main object, alongside additional attributes added to certain inner objects.

I tried to empty the new collections.
Added this line  Mapper.Configuration.CompileMappings(); after AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize();

Comment: you are using Automapper version 6.0.0 ?

Comment: Hello J.Memisevic! Yes!

Comment: Not sure why, why don't you just update your automapper . latest version is 13.0.1 - version that you are using is not compatible with .net6 .

Comment: Hello again! I found the problem... one of the inner property is an ICollection and somewhere in the code it is set to a List type value. The problem of this List is that before assigning it to the property ICollection, there are added some new elements using AdRange() and from here the problem starts.. adding the new elements using a simple foreach solved the problem

Comment: Still don't know why it was important for automaper that there was used AddRange/ 
@J.Memisevic,  do you have an explanation?

Comment: Not sure unless you post a code